# Hiding unwanted properties in custom controls

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gdi+

Is this the way to hide properties in derived controls?

`public class NewButton : Button`

...

```
[Browsable ( false )]
public new ContentAlignment TextAlign { get; set; }
```

Also this hides the property in the Properties window in the designer but how can I also hide the property in code?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From code, the closest you can do it to hide it, and perhaps make it a pain to call directly - note that even when hidden it is callable, and none of this will work past a cast:

```
// about the closest you can do, but not really an answer
[Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
[Obsolete("just cast me to avoid all this hiding...", true)]
public new ContentAlignment TextAlign { get; set; }
```

Personally, I wouldn't bother. It isn't robust (just cast).

Comment: Thanks Marc. By cast you mean casting to the parent class in this case, Button?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `[EditorBrowsable]` attribute, as [documented here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute.aspx).

```
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public bool HideMeInIntellisense
{
    // ...
```

From the documentation:

> ...the IntelliSense engine in Visual Studio uses this attribute to determine whether to show a property or method.

However, users can override this in VS settings.  ReSharper also has a setting that controls whether this attribute is honoured in its IntelliSense.

Out of curiousity, why do you want to hide something from users?  Just because a member is  hidden in the way described above doesn't mean you couldn't use it in code and compile it successfully.  It just inhibits the discoverability of the member.

Comment: By hiding I meant to completely "remove" it so you can't access it. It's because some of the properties of Button doesn't apply to my control.

Comment: Have you considered subclassing a parent of the Button class and reimplementing what you need?  I would consider asking a new question that digs into the reason why you need to change the button's behavior and looks for different ways to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you want to do is derive from ContainerControl or UserControl, add a Button to that control and just expose those parts of the Button interface you want to keep.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can remove them from the designer (as shown) but you cannot really hide them form code as that would violate the substitution principle. It has been asked & answered many times here, see for example [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528/hiding-inherited-members-in-c).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make it private? It guarantees that ancestors will not see it.
Edit: 
In this case you have to inherit a new class from the base and use your new class, which now hides ths property.

```
public class MyTextBox: TextBox
{
...
        private new ContentAlignment TextAlign
        {
          get { return base.ContentAlignment; }
          set { base.ContentAlignment = value; }
        }
}
```

Comment: Because this might or might not be possible. Sometimes you just want to hide something from the GUI.

Comment: I just tried this - the property still appears in the designer.