# Hiding PictureBox's property

Tags: c#, oop

I can override the Name property when the property is public but when I set it private it inherits Picturebox's Name. I want to make it private because I don't want this property to be shown in the objects that generated from MyPictureBox class. Thanks.

```
class MyPictureBox : PictureBox
{
    private string name;
    private new string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: No it does not throw an error. For example when I create an object from MyPictureBox I can still use myPictureBox.Name. I don't want it to be appeared.

Answer (score 1):

I believe SO has an answer for you right here: [Hiding unwanted properties in custom controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528371/hiding-unwanted-properties-in-custom-controls)

Comment: With this answers I decided to use composition instead of inheritance :)