# Unhiding wanted properties in custom controls

Tags: c#, properties, c++-cli, controls, windows-forms-designer

My issue is basically the opposite of [Hiding unwanted properties in custom controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528371/hiding-unwanted-properties-in-custom-controls).

I have created my own ProgressBar with text support based on the description I found [here at SO: 3529928/how-do-i-put-text-on-progressbar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3529945/2505186). It works really great. I have slightly modified it for my use: I don't use the new property `CustomText` of that example, I use the built-in `Text` of the `Controls` base class.

ProgressBar by default has no use for `Text`, thus it's hidden in the designer. How can I unhide it?

I tried to overload it in order to apply the `[Browsable(true)]` attribute, but it doesn't work yet:

```
[Browsable (true)]
virtual property String^    Text      { String^ get()             override;
                                        void    set(String^ text) override; };
```

What else do I have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deleting Visual Studio 2008's temporary files in
`C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\ProjectAssemblies\`
and deleting the .suo and .ncb,
and restarting VS2008,
...
the properties became visible. So it's a designer updating failure, but the code works. :-)