# Serialize XML without tag name

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xmlserializer, xmlroot

I have the following XML format:-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>        
<Price xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <amount>
    <currency>USD</currency>
    100
  </amount>
  <amount>
    <currency>EUR</currency>
    50
  </amount>
</Price>
```

the XML value contains the amount in the xml root. May I know how can I serialize the value of 100 & 50 ?

```
    [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot("amount")]
    public sealed class amount
    {
        [XmlElement("currency")]
        public string currency{ get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list = new List<amount> {new amount() {Description = "USD"}, new amount() {Description = "EUR"}};
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<amount>), new XmlRootAttribute("Price"));
            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            serializer.Serialize(ms, list);
            ms.Position = 0;
            var result = new StreamReader(ms).ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`XmlText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltextattribute(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
[XmlRoot("amount")]
public sealed class amount
{
    [XmlElement("currency")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    // http://stackoverflow.com/a/1528429/613130
    [XmlIgnore]
    public int Value { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public string ValueXml
    {
        get
        {
            return XmlConvert.ToString(Value);
        }
        set
        {
            Value = XmlConvert.ToInt32(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use [`XmlConvert.ToDecimal()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.todecimal(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`XmlConvert.Tostring()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) (or the corresponding `ToInt32()` method) to correctly ignore culture and parse in an invariant format.

Comment: it worked perfectly, but it is important to say that the `[Browsable(false),EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]` attribute is also needed