# Deriving from Control but hiding properties

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Yes, I am aware this has been asked and answered before, but nothing fully addresses several issues.

**References**

- [Hiding inherited members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528/hiding-inherited-members-in-c)
- [Hiding unwanted properties in custom controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528371/hiding-unwanted-properties-in-custom-controls)

Essentially, I'd like to derive from `Control` but without exposing certain properties.  In my case, I am designing a `Container`, which will contain many `Element`s, arranged in a programmatic way.  I'd like (and may *require*) that `Element` derives from `Control`, in order to get all of the drawing and events, but also be able to add `Element` objects to the `Container`'s `Children` collection (for obvious reasons).

The only problem is, if `Element` derives from `Control`, then its `Location` property is exposed, and the user could easily destroy the programmatic placement.  Naturally, my instinct is to keep all the goodies that come along with `Control` and hide/disable the `Location`.

I'm aware of the following:

- This violates the SOLID Liskov substitution principle (design by contract)
- This has been asked before
- I could encapsulate `Control` in my `Element` and forward all of the calls to those of `Control`

  - This would be a ridiculous amount of work, and for no real gain.
  - The encapsulating `Element` would still not be type-compatible with `Control` and could not be used in many cases where a derived form of `Control` would.

I feel there must be some more elegant solution to this (seemingly) recurring problem. Thank you in advance!

**Edit**

The only way I see to accomplish this is:

```
public class Element : Control
{
    public new Point Location { get; private set; }
}
```

But then, I have the problem of, how does my container class set the `Element`s location? In C++ one would use a friend class. I suppose if I kept this control in its own assembly, I could mark the setter as `internal`.

**Edit**

For those looking to do something this, my solution was: to not do it.  Instead, I made a custom object and implemented all of the clicking / dragging, etc myself.  It was just too complicated to try and use a Control, while excluding functionality like Location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot completely prevent the *Control.Location* property from being updated by a determined programmer. Using the *new* keyword will change the accessiblity of the property but it only applies to *Element* and *Element* derived class references. If the programmer casts the instance reference to the base class of *Control* then they can access the original *Location* property and so can update the value. If you do not care about this workaround then simply go ahead and use the override that you have shown in the question.

To truely prevent anyone setting the location except your container then you would have to do a little more work in the following way. Any change to a controls *Location* or *Size* is actually implemented by making a call to the virtual *SetBoundsCore* method. So you could override this virtual method in your *Element* class and ignore all attempted changes except when an instance variable such as *AllowChange* is set. Then in your container you set that *AllowChange* just before updating the size/location and then reset it back afterwards. Now the only way to change the size is by your container or if the programmer uses the little known update property.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like you're trying to create a replacement method (since you worry about the replaceability of "Location")  so either you create a pair of methods for "Location" that merely stub out the fact that they can't update the underlying one (so you're creating an override for the properties you don't want affected) or you ignore the Liskov SOLID principles because that's not what you're doing.

Comment: Right - I wasn't terribly concerned about SOLID, but I knew if I didn't mention it, it would get brought up. But how do you do this? "Location" is not override-able, and if you mark it as "private new", then the base class Location is still directly available.

Comment: Ideally, yes. But then you can't put it somewhere that expects a `Control`, like another control's `Controls` collection.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to go about this is going to be the use of an internal control object. This is completely untested and I'm not yet certain about the accessibility of all interfaces, but this is the way I would start out:

```
[ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
[ClassInterfaceAttribute(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDispatch)]
public class Element : Component, IDropTarget, ISynchronizeInvoke, IWin32Window, 
IBindableComponent, IComponent, IDisposable
{
    private Control _control;
}
```

Here you have the ability to completely hide or expose any properties you choose. Any of your interfaces members can simply refer to the internal control properties.

HTH