# Hiding a property of a WPF control from the Designer (Visual Studio 2010)

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and WPF.

I'm creating a new Control that inherits from ContentControl and I wanna hide the Content property so it will be invisible in the Properties window at design time.

I tried with

```
[Browsable(false)]
```

like we do in WinForms but it doesn't work.

Any idea about how to solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: More code might be helpful. e.g. the definition of the property you're trying to hide.

Comment: Possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528/hiding-inherited-members-in-c-sharp

Comment: [Browsable(false)]
private new object Content
{
  get { return base.Content; }
  set { base.Content = value; }
}

Comment: @Nayan this question is different than the link you sent

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Michelle,

Your property needs to be set to public:

```
[Browsable(false)]
public new object Content
{
    get { return base.Content; }
    set { base.Content = value; }
}
```

Once you set it to public, it will hide from the properties window.

**With Private:**

[image]

**With Public:**

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Jason thank you for your help. Now it works.

But now I've another problem... I've declared it in a base class when I create a new class inheriting from that base class then the Content property appear again in the Properties window.

However if I move the Content property re-declaration to the new class it disappears from the Properties Window.

Why is this happening?

Comment: @Michelle not sure if I'm following, but I was able to create a "BaseControl" class which inherited ContentControl. Then my "MyControl" inherited "BaseControl". If i put the public new object Content in either class, it remains hidden on the form.

Comment: if you don't rewrite the property again in the "MyControl" then it appears in the Property window. However when I do the same in Forms I don't have to rewrite the properties in the derived classes. Why is this happening in WPF?

Comment: wait, so in order to protect a dp from edit via the designer we have to expose it as public? This is counterproductive, surely?

Comment: @TheHitchenator TBH, I answered this 9 years ago. I no longer use WPF, so I can't really provide a solid answer to your question. I do apologize, but yeah, it does seem counterproductive.